# How to wait for pulseaudio before running chromium?

Tags: debian, pulseaudio, embedded, browser

I'm developing an embedded board (Tinkerboard) based on Linux Linaro (Debian) OS 9.3.

The board is basically a (webpage) kiosk where the browser is run by a sh script included the automatic scripts on startup. The kiosk needs to play a couple of mp3 files triggered by js events.

Most of the times the audio is not reproduced: if i manually run the browser the audio is always ok.

So far, I found that the chromium process is run before pulseaudio process (based on PIDs values) so i supposed the browser does not 'connect' the audio process cause missing.

I modified the script something like:

```
 # Script.sh
 pulseaudio
 sleep 4s
 chromium -kiosk ....
```

In this way the audio is ok but I don't like it.. first of all because I'm not sure the cause of the problem.

Is there a way to put in the right sequence the processes?

Any other reasons about the audio problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems *exactly* the kind of problem a sensible init system solves:

Starting services and programs in the right order, and exactly when the things they depend on are ready; not earlier, and not a fixed 4s seconds later than the last start, "just to make sure".

On Debian 9, you'd use a systemd service to initiate the user session that runs wayland or Xorg, on which you then start and show the chromium.

Instead of manually starting processes one after the other without *actually* checking whether they've started:

You'd simply define a chromium-kiosk.service user service, which depends on pulseaudio.service; starting that will wait until the pulseaudio service has started. How to do that is explained in many places, e.g. [here](https://superuser.com/a/1128905/563936).

Other advantages of doing that include automatic restarting of chromium if it ever crashes, logging of failures to start, ability to make the chromium process itself a requirement for other services. Most importantly, you can actually say "hey, for a full boot you need to start chromium", and your system will make sure everything necessary for that will boot.